# Data not inserting

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, pdo

So my form isn't inserting data into mysql. I'm pretty sure everything is correct.
Here's the form

And heres my `index.php`

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../assets/ico/favicon.ico">

    <title>Signin Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="signin.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy this line! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.1/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">

      <form class="form-signin" role="form" action="register.php" method="post">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign up</h2>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name"  name="name" autofocus>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"  name="username" autofocus>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"  name="email" autofocus>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password, Again" name="passwordconf" >
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign up</button>
      </form>

    </div> <!-- /container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
  </body>
</html>
```

`register.php`

```
  <?php
//Connection
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=s', 'root', '*');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

//Post
$name = $_POST['name'];
$username =$_POST['username'];
$email $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$password1 = $_POST['passwordconf'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


//Insert into datbase
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO userinfo (name ,username, email, password, ip) VALUES (:name,:username,:email,:password,:ip)';    
    $query = $handler->prepare($sql);

    $query->execute(array(

    ':name' => $name,
    ':username' => $username,
    ':email' => $email,
    ':password' => $password,
    ':ip' => $ip

    ));

?>
```

The connection is successful and all rows exist in the database. I'm not really sure where to go now or what to do. Any ideas would be great.

Comment: Maybe you're missing some inverted commas. What error message do you get?

Comment: Check your error log...what does it say?

Comment: None. I just don't see dataloading into the database and using firebug I get an error on POST, but I can't see what it is @Strawberry

Comment: There are no errors. @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob

Comment: Did you bother to read _anything_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Wrong variable:**

```
$query = $handler->prepare($sql);
```

**correction:**

```
$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
```

You have forgotten equal sign(I would suggest you to use some IDE to ignore such silly mistakes):

```
$email $_POST['email'];
```

**correction:**

```
$email =  $_POST['email'];
```

Comment: I put your code in netbeans and it directly pointed me the mistake :D :D

Comment: thanks @jeroen do smart work instead of hard work. when you have already pointed one of the mistakes, whats the point of me typing it again. I just found the other mistake and completed the answer. Thanks for down voting too -> bad attitude

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the wrong variable:

```
$query = $handler->prepare($sql);
```

should be:

```
$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
```

That would lead to errors though...

Comment: @user3574362 Check your `$conn` object, that probably does not throw an exception as you set that in the second line after you try to open the database connection. Also, have you enabled error display? You probably have errors in the error log if you don't see them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. These was a syntax error in your `$email` variable and `$handler->prepare($sql);` should be `$conn->prepare($sql);`

```
<?php
//Connection
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=s', 'root', '*');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

//Post
$name = $_POST['name'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$password1 = $_POST['passwordconf'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


//Insert into datbase
$sql = 'INSERT INTO userinfo (name ,username, email, password, ip) VALUES (:name,:username,:email,:password,:ip)';
$query = $conn->prepare($sql);

$query->execute(array(
    ':name' => $name,
    ':username' => $username,
    ':email' => $email,
    ':password' => $password,
    ':ip' => $ip
));
?>
```